# Trending Articles - Something new of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have recently spotted this in between my facebook news feed:

[image: Trending Articles - is this something new on facebook?]

Is this some new feature of facebook or is it because of some app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Feature of Facebook. Not any apps. There has been no official announcement about it AFAIK. But you can read more [here at Mashable](http://mashable.com/2012/04/26/facebook-trending-articles-test/).

Comment: Can you give link to some source giving the official news?

Comment: no official announcement. just a small feature. check the answer.